# Program crash when calling OpenGL functions

Tags: c++, opengl, game-engine, glew

I'm trying to setup a game engine project. My visual studio project is setup so that I have an 'engine' project separate from my 'game' project. Then engine project is being compiled to a dll for the game project to use. I've already downloaded and setup glfw and glew to start using openGL. My problem is when ever I hit my first openGL function the program crashes. I know this has something to do with glewinit even though glew IS initializing successfully (no console errors). In my engine project, I have a window class where, upon window construction, glew should be setup:

Window.h

```
#pragma once
#include "GL\glew.h"
#include "GLFW\glfw3.h"

#if (_DEBUG)
#define LOG(x) printf(x)
#else
#define LOG(x)
#endif

namespace BlazeGraphics
{

    class __declspec(dllexport) Window
    {
    public:
        Window(short width, short height, const char* title);
        ~Window();

        void Update();
        void Clear() const;
        bool Closed() const; 

    private:
        int m_height;
        int m_width;
        const char* m_title;
        GLFWwindow* m_window;

    private:
        Window(const Window& copy) {}
        void operator=(const Window& copy) {}
    };

}
```

Window.cpp (where glewinit() is called)

```
#include "Window.h"
#include <cstdio>

namespace BlazeGraphics
{

    //Needed to define outside of the window class (not sure exactly why yet)
    void WindowResize(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);

    Window::Window(short width, short height, const char* title) :
        m_width(width),
        m_height(height),
        m_title(title)
    {
        //InitializeWindow
        {
            if (!glfwInit())
            {
                LOG("Failed to initialize glfw!");
                return;
            };

            m_window = glfwCreateWindow(m_width, m_height, m_title, NULL, NULL);
            if (!m_window)
            {
                LOG("Failed to initialize glfw window!");
                glfwTerminate();
                return;
            };

            glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_window);
            glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(m_window, WindowResize);
        }

        //IntializeGl
        {
            //This needs to be after two functions above (makecontextcurrent and setwindowresizecallback) or else glew will not initialize
            **if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
            {
                LOG("Failed to initialize glew!");
            }**
        }
    }


    Window::~Window()
    {
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    void Window::Update()
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(m_window);
    }

    void Window::Clear() const
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    //Returns a bool because glfwwindowShouldClose returns a nonzero number or zero
    bool Window::Closed() const
    {
        //Made it equal to 1 to take away warning involving converting an int to bool
        return glfwWindowShouldClose(m_window) == 1;
    }

    //Not part of window class so defined above
    void WindowResize(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
    {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

}
```

Here is my main.cpp file which is found within my game project where I currently have my openGL functionality in global functions (just for now):

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include "GL\glew.h"
#include "GLFW\glfw3.h"
#include "../Engine/Source/Graphics/Window.h"

void initializeGLBuffers()
{
    GLfloat triangle[] =
    {
        +0.0f, +0.1f, -0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.1f, -0.1f, 0.0f, //1
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

        +0.1f, -0.1f, 0.0f, //2
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    GLuint bufferID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle), triangle, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (sizeof(GLfloat)) * 6, nullptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (sizeof(GLfloat)) * 6, (char*)((sizeof(GLfloat)) * 3));

    GLushort indices[] =
    {
        0,1,2
    };

    GLuint indexBufferID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
};


void installShaders()
{
    //Create Shader
    GLuint vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    //Add source or text file to shader object
    std::string temp = readShaderCode("VertexShaderCode.glsl");
    const GLchar* adapter[1];

    adapter[0] = temp.c_str();
    glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, 1, adapter, 0);
    temp = readShaderCode("FragmentShaderCode.glsl").c_str();
    adapter[0] = temp.c_str();
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, adapter, 0);

    //Compile Shadaer
    glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

    if (!checkShaderStatus(vertexShaderID) || !checkShaderStatus(FragmentShaderID))
        return;

    //Create Program
    GLuint programID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(programID, FragmentShaderID);

    //Link Program
    glLinkProgram(programID);

    if (!checkProgramStatus(programID))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to link program";
        return;
    }

    //Use program
    glUseProgram(programID);
}

int main()
{

    BlazeGraphics::Window window(1280, 720, "MyGame");

    initializeGLBuffers();
    installShaders();

    while (!window.Closed())
    {
        window.Clear();

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

        window.Update();
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Now if I were to move the glewinit() code here in my main.cpp:

```
int main()
{

    BlazeGraphics::Window window(1280, 720, "MyGame");

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
            {
                LOG("Failed to initialize glew!");
            }

    initializeGLBuffers();
    installShaders();

    while (!window.Closed())
    {
        window.Clear();

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

        window.Update();
    };

    return 0;
}
```

then my program compiles fine. Why does trying to initialize glew within engine.dll cause a program crash? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Desktop. I accidentally added opengl-es tag, removed it now

Comment: you can call `glewInit` only if your OpenGL context is already created otherwise you will hit the wall... I do not see any OpenGL initialization ... may be it is hidden inside `BlazeGraphics::Window window(1280, 720, "MyGame");`. Also the `glewInit` and all OpenGL stuff should be called from the same thread ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GLEW works by defining a function pointer as  **global variable** for each OpenGL function. Let's look at `glBindBuffer` as an example:

```
#define GLEW_FUN_EXPORT GLEWAPI

typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC) (GLenum target, GLuint buffer);
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC __glewBindBuffer;
```

So we just have a `__glewBindBuffer` function pointer, which will be set to the correct address from your OpenGL implementation by `glewInit`.

To actually be able to write `glBindBuffer`, GLEW simply defines pre-processor macros mapping the GL functions to those function pointer variables:

```
#define glBindBuffer GLEW_GET_FUN(__glewBindBuffer);
```

> Why does trying to initialize glew within `engine.dll` cause a program crash?

Because your `engine.dll` and your main application each  have a separate set of all of these global variables. You would have to export all the `__glew*` variables from your engine DLL to be able to get access to the results of your `glewInit` call in `engine.dll`.

Comment: Thank you for some clarification. What would be the best way to make sure to export all the glew variables to be used in the game project? Would dynamically linking glew instead of statically linking it in engine do the trick?

Comment: @Jason: Honestly: You probably shouldn't do that, because the function pointers may differ between contexts. Technically you'd have to call `glewInit` every time the context is switched. The proper solution would be to have a struct or class holding all the function pointers and do the calls through that. You could then just pass around a pointer to that struct between DLLs. – Of course the design of most OpenGL loaders doesn't permit it to do this easily. I suggest you just call `glewInit` in every module that requires it.

Comment: Wow really? Thats very interesting. I never would have thought that to be the case. Thanks for the heads up datenwolf